# strtok does not appear to modify the input string

Tags: c++, c

I've always understood that `strtok` should be regarded with caution due to the fact that it modifies its input string by inserting NULLs at the last token locations. This is also validated by [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

However, on trying to validate an [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) from cplusplus.com, I found that in VS2010 in 32 bit Windows 7, strtok is in fact NOT inserting NULLs in the original string. I was able to determine this by modifying the NULL in the argument from the example to str, and the program loops repeatedly, passing "This" as the token, which (as I interpreted this), is not the same behavior as passing the previous pointer, as cppreference claims.

In addition, I thought maybe the const-ness of string literals may have been at fault, so I copied the string

```
char str2[] ="- This, a sample string.";
char str[50];
strcpy(str,str2);
```

and ran it again, but the loop repeated. Debugger shows that the input string is not modified.

Can someone explain where I am going wrong here? *edit: I think it's my interpretation of "The behavior is the same as if the previously stored pointer is passed as str."*

Thank you.

EDIT: exact code:

```
/* strtok example */
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str2[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char str[50];
  strcpy(str,str2);
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (str, " ,.-");
    printf("%s\n", str);
  }
  std::cin.ignore();
  return 0;
}
```

Output from code:

```
Splitting string "- This, a sample string." into tokens:
This
- This
This
- This
This
- This
This
- This
This
- This
This
- This
This
- This
```

EDIT: RESOLVED Should I delete this garbage or let it stay? haha I don't want to take points away from the poor people who had to deal with this

Comment: @nos good call thanks, debated making the post seem longer than necessary as the example was the second link I posted

Comment: So? You posted the code. Fine. Now, what made you think the string was not modified? I don't see any attempts to analyze the value `str` in the code. How did you come to the conclusion it wasn't modified?

Comment: @AndreyT ah sorry, I checked it in the debugger, would have posted images but imgur is blocked at work

Comment: The easiest way to check if the string was modified is to insert a `printf("%s\n", str);` inside the loop, after the call to strtok()

Comment: @AK4749: The string that you should watch for modifications is `str`. `str` will be modified by the first call to `strtok`. I assume that in the debugger you were mistakenly watching `str2`.

Comment: @AndreyT I made sure i didn't do that by accident and just doublechecked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it is not `NULL` that is inserted into the original string, it is a zero-character that is inserted. While I understand that this is probably what you wanted to say, it is still  not a good idea to involve a well-known and completely unrelated macro `NULL`.

Secondly, if `strtok` fails inserting zero characters into the original string, it simply won't work as intended. For this reason I strongly believe that you somehow misinterpreted the results of your experiments. `strtok` does modify the input string even in VS2010 under 32 bit Windows 7.

---

The output from your code you posted clearly shows that the string was *modified*. The original value of `str` was `"- This, a sample string."`. The value of `str` printed from inside the loop is just `"- This"`. The string got truncated specifically because `strtok` inserted a zero-character right after `"- This"` (more precisely, the `,` character got *replaced* with `\0` character).

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix that, I got caught up with NULL-character from the reference wording and forgot to carry that over. Yes, that was what I had assumed, can you see where I am going wrong in the example code?

Comment: @AK4749: To clarify, "NUL" (with one L) refers to the 0-byte at the end of the string, whereas "NULL" specifically refers to a null pointer (of any type).  To avoid confusion, I generally avoid using NUL and refer to it as the 0-byte or the null terminator.

Comment: There we go, don't I feel silly, that was it hahaha I was looking for the '\0' in the wrong place lol....From the wording I somehow expected "T" to go NUL, which is obviously not correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> I was able to determine this by modifying the NULL in the argument from the example to str, and the program loops repeatedly

It does this because when you pass in `str` (or a non-NULL pointer), `strtok()` starts over, so it will just tokenize what's now a single token (returning it over and over). That's the documented behavior when a non-NULL pointer is passed in to `strtok()`.

When you pass in `NULL` as the first argument to `strtok()` that tells it to pick up where it left off last time (it keeps track of that state in a static variable somewhere, which is one of the problems with `strtok()`).

Comment: From the [`strtok(3)` documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok): "On the first call to `strtok()` the string to be parsed should be specified in `str`. In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, `str` should be `NULL`."  Also note that `strtok` is not thread-safe or reentrant, so if you're working in a multithreaded program or could potentially be tokenizing multiple strings at once, use `strtok_r` instead.

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured it was something like that,